# Compiler doesn't like my class C++. getting undeclared identifier error and more

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I created a class called "Message". I want to store Messages that are created with the class "Message" in a static vector array in a class named "MessageBox". The compiler tells me that Message doesn't exist, but the editor is telling me otherwise. Here are the files with the code:

"Message.h"

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Message Box.h"

namespace ATE {
    class Message
    {
    public:
        Message(std::string act, std::string ID, std::string IDtwo) { action = act, ID1 = ID, ID2 = IDtwo; }
        Message(std::string act, std::string ID) { action = act, ID1 = ID; }

        std::string action;
        std::string ID1;
        std::string ID2 = nullptr;

    };

}
```

"Message Box.h"

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Message.h"

namespace ATE {
    class MessageBox
    {
    public:
        static std::vector<Message> MsgBox;
        void addMessage(Message msg);

    };
}
```

"Message Box.cpp"

```
#include "Message Box.h"

void ATE::MessageBox::addMessage(Message msg)
{
     MsgBox.push_back(msg);
}
```

My errors:

Error C2065 'Message': undeclared identifier       (file: message box.h,    line: 11)

Error   C2923   'std::vector': 'Message' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'                                (file: message box.h, line:   11)

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Message'  (file: message box.h, line: 12)

Help is much appreciated (:

Comment: **"Message.h"**

    #pragma once // do you forget pragma once?
    #include <string>
    // #include "Message Box.h" // why do you include message box in the message.h file?
    ...
    /// std::string ID2 = nullptr; // what do you mean?

Comment: yeah, i had the pragma once, but i forgot to copy it into this question. the #include "Message Box.h" in "Message.h" was from an old message system idea i had but then i started switching stuff around. std::string ID2 = nullptr is because it may never have a value. I took out the Message Box.h" in "Message.h" and now i'm getting link errors

Comment: More in-depth discussion on what happened here: [Resolve header include circular dependencies in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Comment: yeah, i hate refactoring code because i always have little bits left here and there. the 2nd part of the answer below got me out of the link errors. thank you all for your help

Comment: You're compiling with Visual Studio, so be aware that `windows.h` has the nasty habit of #defining `MessageBox`. You might suddenly see an error on `ATE::MessageBoxW`, macro's do not respect scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your headers include each other. Due to the `#pragma once` if you include `Message.h` first in some .cpp file the compiler will see `Message Box.h`'s content "inside" `Message.h` - exactly at the `#include "Message Box.h"` line. As result the compiler will process your source code in the following order:

```
source.cpp:
  //#include "Message.h"
message.h:
  //#pragma once
  //#include <iostream>
iostream:
  //iostream's content
message.h(resumed):
  //#include <string>
string:
  //string's content
message.h(resumed):
  #include "Message Box.h"
Message Box.h:
  #pragma once
  #include <string>
  // string's content already included, won't include again
  #include <vector>
  // vector's content
  #include "Message.h"
  // message.h won't include again, due to the #pragma once

  namespace ATE {
      class MessageBox
      {
      public:
          static std::vector<Message> MsgBox;
```

At this point the name `Message` is used, but the compiler has not reached it's definition in `Message.h` yet and gives you an error.

Removing the `#pragma once` won't help. You need to remove the circular dependency. In this case remove the `#include "Message Box.h"` from `Message.h` and you'll be fine.

Comment: thank you for the full explanation, i appreciate it. I accidentally left that header in when refactoring code and didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

1. In "Message.h", remove the:

   `#include "Message Box.h"`

It add the `Message Box` declaration before the `Message`.

2. In "Message Box.cpp" Add this line after the includes:

   `std::vector<ATE::Message> ATE::MessageBox::MsgBox;`

A `static` member must be declared again outside.

Comment: Thank you, that works (:   I'm a bit rusty with C++ as you can tell. Haven't programmed in it for a few months